# What are the options for swagger-editor to save json or yaml into remote backend?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I know that the Swagger-editor saves api documentation into the local browser cache ("Download Yaml/Json" and "Export Yaml/Json").

But what if I want to save it into a remote server then latter I can continue editing it from another browser.

Are there already known Backends for Swagger-editor which I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parse is nice. You can easily use it for a simple BaaS: http://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/. Totally free as well

Answer (score 2):

The [swagger-node project](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) has the editor built in and saves files in your filesystem.

Follow the steps in the README to install and run. When you make changes in the editor that you launch (your browser), they are autosaved, and you can see the change in the `api` directory. For example, if you change the `{ info: { title } }` key, you'll see it autosave and then you can see the change in `./api/swagger/swagger.yaml`.

Comment: Looks good but what if I have multiple specification files along with multiple teams working on it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to `useBackendForStorage: true` which does a HTTP put to a backend server.

Comment: I just wanted to know if I enable this option what a backend server I can use from some of the existing ones.

Comment: You'll have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the game, but maybe helps others:

There is a very simple backend here, written in go:
https://github.com/zgiber/sweb

It runs as a http server on your localhost, and opens the editor in a browser. Saves the swagger file as you type.