# What should I code, if i want swagger-editor to save into remote server

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I have read the question [What are the options for swagger-editor to save json or yaml into remote backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124472/what-are-the-options-for-swagger-editor-to-save-json-or-yaml-into-remote-backend), but i still have a question, where to find the interface document that implements backend storage by swagger-editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use swagger-editor to create a backend storage for swagger-editor.  It will simply do a POST to the server when configured.  Or use an existing service like https://swaggerhub.com

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want to deploy 'swagger-edit' on my severs.
If i modify "default.confg", my chrome will request "/editor/spec", and get 404 error. 
Could you help me to complete this? And my question is what reponse should return from my server?

Comment: @Jaxonwei how did you figure this out?